# Update a Table to add a new column and set values via a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table R which in part has a column C. I have another table T which also has a column C that is of the same type and points to the same variable.

I want to perform a LEFT JOIN between R and T on C so that I return the full contents of R back, but with a column D from T, i.e.

```
SELECT R.*, T.D 
FROM R LEFT JOIN T 
ON R.C = T.C
```

Note - The LEFT JOIN here is used as I only want to match those rows of T to R that exists in T and when it doesn't exist in R, I want a NULL value.

Now, I want the returned Query to be the new definition of R. i.e.

Note - the following is pseudocode.

```
 R = (
     SELECT R.*, T.D 
     FROM R LEFT JOIN T 
     ON R.C = T.C
    
    )
```

The method I tried was the following:

```
CREATE TABLE "R" AS 
   SELECT R.*, T.D 
   FROM R LEFT JOIN T 
   ON R.C = T.C
```

This produces an error. It seems that SQL (here I'm using SQLite) does not allow for this sort of reallocation.

I'm unsure how to proceed - does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for a [VIEW](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html)?

Comment: @Shawn - Not at this stage.

Comment: What you are describing is a View. You can' create a table that contains a column from another table.

Comment: @forpas - Perhaps, but I do want the underlying table altered.

Comment: Also - or those that have down-voted - what have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new column and assign it a value:

```
alter table r add column d <type>;
```

Then you can populate it:

```
update r
    set d = (select t.d from t where t.c = r.c);
```

However, a view seems more useful.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed (can't believe I didn't think of it myself). 

In terms of Views - I've barely used them - do you know of any good resources to learn about them?

Comment: Just did, I thought I had but had just 'up-voted' - Sorry, I'm new here!